# Create PDF using Matlab

Tags: matlab

In this  https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/392471-hi-how-can-i-generate-a-pdf-file-in-matlab-with-information-from-code they use the following script below to  create a PDF

```
%%publish example
X = randn(1,100);
mean(x)
std(x)
hist(X)
```

How did they do it? I can not see how to use the publish command in a script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the code used to produce a PDF, that's the example code that they publish.

They use the "Publish" tab of the MATLAB GUI to publish that code (outputting it to a PDF).

`Publish` -> `Publish` -> `Edit Publishing Options` -> `Output Format: PDF`

To publish from a script, use the `publish` command.

```matlab
publish('myfile.m','pdf');
```

(`help publish` for more)

Comment: OK. Any other way to produce a PDF without using the report generator?

Comment: Yes, see `publish('myfile.m','pdf');` in my answer above.

Comment: I mean to save part of a script, not all of it.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to write a new temporary script that contains just the part you want. But you should update your question to describe what you'd like to do in any event.